# Strapi API SingleTypes return 404

Tags: strapi

I have a Single Type called global and I try to access it using `http://localhost:1337/api/global` in Postman but I get in return

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 404,
        "name": "NotFoundError",
        "message": "Not Found",
        "details": {}
    }
}
```

Inside roles I have access to all permissions to Global. If I am going to request any Collection Types it will work as expected.

Any idea what could be the reason?